# What is the ExtJS 4 alternative to enableHdMenu?

Tags: extjs4

In ExtJS 3, you could set enableHdMenu to false on a Grid to remove the little trigger at the end of the column name, which has the dropdown menu containing the sort directions and options for hiding columns.

How do I hide this trigger and menu in ExtJS 4? I know that I can set enableColumnHide to false to remove the hiding options, but I want to remove the trigger completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The config is [`menuDisabled`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-menuDisabled)

> True to disable the column header menu containing sort/hide options. Defaults to false.

Comment: You're welcome. You can always do a Ctrl+F on the related class to do a quick text search to see related configuration. And thanks for asking this because I never know `enableHdMenu` has been replaced!

Comment: I think it's annoying that they changed it to per column only. In case  someone looks at this you can set a defaults: clause on the column configuration object to have it for all columns (in extjs 4). `columns: { defaults: { menuDisabled: true }, columns: [...] }`

Comment: It appears the correct config option within the columns object is now called "items" instead of "columns"; so: `columns: { defaults: { menuDisabled: true }, items: [...] }`

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Lionel's answer, bear in mind that the previous enableHdMenu config option for grids has moved to individual columns config.

If you need a slightly faster way of applying this and other defaults to all columns in your grid, you could do something like this:

```
  var columnDefaults = {
    menuDisabled : true,
    hideable : false,
    resizable : true
}


columns = [
    ...
    Ext.applyIf({id : 'mimeType', header : 'Mime', hideable : true, width : 100, dataIndex : 'mimeType'}, columnDefaults),
    ...
]
```

This will allow you to override when necessary.

I also agree that the movement of this to columns is annoying. There are other grid-wide config options such as enableColumnHide available, so why not thi?